# How to load word application once the user authenticaton is performed and then load add-in?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, add-in

I have One Solution containing 3 projects- class library, windows Forms project and Word Add in. Word Add-in is startup project.
 i want to authenticate user and then load word application with add-in
I can authenticate user with windows forms but before authentication i dont want word application to load. is it possible to delay Word Application loading till the authentication is performed? or suggest me any other workaround.
i have validated user in this way-

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {  WinProj.Forms.Login loginObj = new WinProj.Forms.Login();
        loginObj.Show();
        loginObj.Focus();
        if (loginObj.UserValidated != null)
            if (loginObj.UserValidated != "")
            {
                EnableDisableAddIn(Application, true);//enable add-in
            }
            else
            {
                EnableDisableAddIn(Application, false);//disable add-in
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer. It was very simple. Before login i  set

```
    WinProj.Forms.Login loginObj = new WinProj.Forms.Login();
    loginObj.Show();
    loginObj.Focus(); 
    loginObj.Activate();
    Application.Visible = false;;
```

and in login form's login button click event i validated the user and make the application visible.